# How to rotate a vector towards another vector in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My projectile has an unit vector called movementDirection, which is multiplied by speed and Time.deltaTime in order to move the projectile towards a direction each Update(); This works correctly.

However, I want to add in projectile homing. The issue is though, this homing in must have max rotation rate to feel more natural. On top of this, my game uses pixel art, so I cannot rotate the object.

There doesn't seem to be a proper way to do this, whatever I attempt, the projectile doesn't move towards the target, instead having weird behavior.

For example: This causes the projectile to not home in at all, instead flipping movementDirection for some reason.

```
void Start()
{
    homingDirection = movementDirection;
}

void Update()
{
    if (homing)
    {
        if (FindTarget())
        {
            // calculate the direction towards the target
            targetDirection = trackingEnemy.position - transform.position;
                
            targetAngle = 90 + Mathf.Max(Vector3.Angle(targetDirection, homingDirection), maxRotationRate);

            if (trackingEnemy.position.y < transform.position.y)
            {
                targetAngle *= -1;
            }

            homingDirection = RotateVector(movementDirection, targetAngle * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        transform.Translate(Time.deltaTime * speed * new Vector3(homingDirection.x, homingDirection.y, 0));
    }
}
```

Here's an image of what I want to create:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0qkl.png)

Answer (score 1):

Wow, just found the issue. I had to rotate targetDirection by -90 degrees, because my prefab is rotated by -90 degrees. That's stupid.

"you can answer your own solution tomorrow" - well here's my stamp of approval then: *